# How to run a non-static function in a new thread in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, non-static

I am trying to code a basic game in C++. I have a class called player with a function called *moveLeft();* which constantly monitors the "a" get that I want to run in a separate thread.

Calling it how I thought I was supposed to. I now understand that this is because it's a non-static function, but I'm unsure of how to do this now. I am using the <thread> library.

#### Player class

```
#pragma once
class player
{
    public:
        player(); // Constructor
        ~player(); // Destructor

        void moveLeft();
        void moveRight();
        void jump(double);

        int getHealth();

        double get_x_position();
        double get_y_position();

        double get_x_momentum();
        double get_y_momentum();

        bool getGrounded();

        void setHealth(int);

        void set_x_position(double);
        void set_y_position(double);

        void set_x_momentum(double);
        void set_y_momentum(double);

        void setGrounded(bool);

    private:
        int health;

        bool grounded;

        double x_position;
        double y_position;

        double x_momentum;
        double y_momentum;
};
```

#### moveLeft() function

```
void player::moveLeft()
{
    while (true)
    {
        while (GetKeyState(97))
        {
            if (grounded)
            {
                x_momentum -= .01;
            }
            else
            {
                x_momentum -= 0.07;
            }

            x_position += x_momentum;
        }
    }
}
```

How I thought I was supposed to set it up.

```
thread t1(&player::moveLeft);
t1.detach();
```

Comment: use static function to start the thread and pass `player` as an argument to it: `thread t1(&run, player)`; in the `run` function call `player->moveLeft()`.

Answer (score 9):

If you are starting the thread from a member function of your class, you are probably looking for

```
thread t1(&player::moveLeft, this);
t1.detach();
```

The reason for including the `this` pointer is that every member function has a hidden parameter, the pointer to the object with which it is associated. `this` in the code above is a `player*`. Of course, you can use any other pointer to `player`, not necessarily `this`. Whatever object you point to, the member function will see it as "this object" inside its body.

Comment: Thank you! But now when I run it I get this error "E0258 'this' may only be used inside a nonstatic member function"

Comment: So you are launching the thread from a static member function? These functions don't see the `this` pointer, they are like global functions in the class namespace.  It won't work this way. You might need to re-evaluate your program architecture.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it that way, you need to create an instance of the player class

```
player *myplayer = new player(); //do this in your initializer, not for every call.
thread t1(&player::moveLeft, myplayer);
t1.detach();
```

The singleton approach posted in another reply will work if you only want one instance of a player.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `std::bind` to solve this problem.

```
thread t1(std::bind(&player::moveLeft,this));
t1.detach();
```

Comment: The use of `std::bind` is essentially deprecated with the advent of lambda's.

Comment: Thank for your reminder.
So let's use the lambda to handle it.
thread t1([&]() { player.moveLeft(); } );
t1.detach();

Comment: `std::bind()` is not necessary, the constructor of thread can take the `this` parameter directly.

Answer (score -1):

With due respect - I believe your program structure or general design is inappropriate.

- You should not have event processing or I/O handling within methods of problem-domain objects.
- If there are constraints to when movement occurs (e.g. not moving left until something happens) - why are there methods exposed which effect movement immediately (e.g. `set_x_position()`)?
- Why bother with private members if you have trivial getters and setters from them? Is it not the case that you should really just drop the setters?
- The player class instance is shared across multiple threads. Should you not be locking it somehow when you alter it in one of them?

To answer your concrete question, though:

```
auto l = [&]() { player1.moveLeft(); }
auto t1 = std::thread{l};
t1.detach();
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I know my code isn't the best. I just started to learn about classes and objects so it'll take me a little while to get the hang of it.

Comment: @diego_rod: No need to apologize - we get that on StackOverflow all the time. The important thing is that you ask questions properly (which you seem to have), not that you be experienced or have good code and good design.